# How do I insert a ahref around my mouseover divs - wordpress keeps removing the ahref

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

on the following site: http://www.strategix.co.za/ on that page you will see the heading OUR SOLUTIONS with the 8 hover over boxes.

what I'm trying to do is to wrap a href around each box so that not only when you hover over does it display the right side div but you can click on the box which takes you to the relevant page.

so in the code:

```
<div class="left2">
<div class="box2">Microsoft Dynamics ERP</div>
</div>
```

I try say:

```
<div class="left2">
<a href="link"><div class="box2">Microsoft Dynamics ERP</div></a>
</div>
```

But the minute I save it in wordpress it removes the ahref. I also tried this:

```
<div class="left2">
<div class="box2"><a href="link"><div>Microsoft Dynamics ERP</a></div></div>
</div>
```

But that didnt save either. I just need each seperate whole box to have an href.

Will appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="left2">
<div class="box2" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='link';">Microsoft Dynamics ERP</div>
</div>
```

Using javascript is one way to apply a link to an entire div.

Comment: I tried that, but Wordpress doesnt save my changes for some reason. I insert it, save it, and when viewing the change, what i inserted for some reason disappears? 

Is there not something I can put in the javascript below:

    <script> 
    var $right2Box2 = $(".right2 .box2");
    $(".left2 .box2").hover(function(){
      $right2Box2.hide();
      $right2Box2.eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
    </script>

Or in the CSS?